# Clear all the value of a datagridview column once in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

i have user below code to  clear the cell value of a datagridview column.

```
For Each item As DataGridViewRow In dgvGeometricImport.Rows
 item.Cells("Status1").Value = String.Empty
Next
```

Do we have any short cut to clear all value without iterating the rows?

can we use linq to achieve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Linq will still iterate the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With or without a `DataSource` set, you can *remove and re-add the column.

VB Example *with* `DataSource` set:

```
Dim index As Integer = Me.dataGridView1.Columns("Status1").DisplayIndex

Dim table As DataTable = DirectCast(Me.dataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim column As DataColumn = table.Columns("Status1")
table.Columns.Remove(column)
table.Columns.Add(column)

Me.dataGridView1.Columns("Status1").DisplayIndex = index
```

VB Example *without* `DataSource` set:

```
Dim index As Integer = Me.dataGridView1.Columns("Status1").Index
Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = Me.dataGridView1.Columns("Status1")
Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(column)
Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, column)
```

---

<sub>***Disclaimer**: This will work, but if I'm being honest I can't say for certain that there's no iteration occurring at some lower level. After all, when you re-add the column it becomes a part of each row entry and therefore could have been iterated through under-the-hood.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
dataGridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).ToList.ForEach(Sub(r) r.Cells("ColumnName").Value = String.Empty)
```

but it's the same thing, linq will do the iteration

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use jQuery selectors. It would of course still iterate through the rows, but it would be done client side and behind the scene.

```
$('#' + gridViewCtlId + ' td:nth-child(' + INDEX_COLUMN_TO_CLEAR + ')').html('');
```